# Do music apps on Android filter small files?

Tags: applications, music-player, mp3, droid-explorer

I have lots of albums containing mp3 files on my Android phone. To listen to these tracks I have tried some music apps, but I am facing the same issue with lots of them : the small mp3 files (< 1 MB or so) are not showing up ! They are displayed if I am using a file explorer app, but not on the music apps, so I cannot listen to them.

Why is it so? Is this normal? Does it depend on my phone, Android version, or only the music apps? Is there a way to stop this? I was not able to find how to remove this filter in the parameters of the apps. Do you have the name of free music apps that do the job?

Thanks

Comment: "I have tried some music apps", which one? I have many small files, use VLC and don't have any issue. Have you tried it?

Comment: Music apps don't use the file system for listing files they use the MediaStore database which is provided by Android system wide. I don't know if MediaStore has size/duration filters but another possibility is that that those small files have a defect and because of this are ignored by MediaStore file indexer. Use a mp3 verifyer program that checks if the files are free of errors in mp3 stream and ID3.

Comment: Well definitely! Android developer here, this is the property/settings of the Musicplayer app, on the lines of what @Robert already mentioned. Medistore definitely allows the duration filter for the developers as a feature. With such setting developer should have given an option of ignoring the files smaller than `X-seconds` and after a rescan it will. Will give you an example of a very famous music player named Poweramp.

Comment: Well, thanks a lot, I have installed Poweramp and it does not suffer this problem ! :)